# Get width of an element without jquery

Tags: javascript

Nevermind this, i did it the oldschool way with counting elements.

I have a few div's inside a main div. Now the top div has a set width, but it's inside varies in width because of the content in it. So if i'm not mistaken, i need the innerWidth. Whatever the case, in this case it needs to result in a width of 600.

I'm not using jquery but jqui, so i would like it in javascript alone seeing jqui does not have an inner-/outerwidth function. This does mean though that I have a $ selector to play with.

```
<style>
  .holder {
    width:100%; /* which in this case is 320px */
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
  }

  .menu_item {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
  }
</style>

<div class="holder" onscroll="get_width(this)">
  <div class="menu_item">
    item1
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    item2
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    item3
  </div>
</div>

get_width(that) {
  alert(that.innerWidth); // returns undefined
  alert(that.width); // returns undefined
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TSQs7/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you are looking for is [element.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth)

Comment: returns 320, which is width of page. i need the inside width

Comment: thanks for this, it returns the exact width of an element

Answer (score 5):

To get the width and height use clientWidth and clientHeight respectively.

```
element.clientWidth
```

**UPDATE:**

**clientWidth is supported even in old ie6**

*Check out this for all platforms support:*

[platforms support reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)

Check out this great article for more in depth info on different width related properties:

[understanding offsetwidth clientwidth scrollwidth and height respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively)

**NOTE:**

> This property will round the value to an integer. If you need a
>   fractional value, use element.getBoundingClientRect().

[clientWidth MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth)

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TSQs7/)

Comment: returns 320, which is width of page. i need the inside width

Comment: Wait a minute I will check and give you the fiddle link

Comment: it gives back a complete object. Which one do i need?

Comment: Wait a minute I will check and give you the fiddle link

Comment: @Matt Check the answer, I added fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/TSQs7/
I am getting 544 as width

Comment: I think i'm a bit assholedhere. I've updated your fiddle with the exact CSS i have and it doesn't work in jsfiddle (some kind of wrapping is going on for some reason). It does however work in phonegap ios and phonegap android (live and working on all phones) and working in all browsers. But your example still returns the screen width, and not the width of the inside, which is what i need.

Comment: ok, so this is the fiddle as it is in my code an how it works everywhere (except in fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/TSQs7/2/

Comment: The fiddle was returning the window width for me.