# element.clientHeight doesn't account for scrollbar height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was hoping to be able to detect scrollbar heights and do other various things described in [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively), given the difference between clientHeight and offsetHeight when scrollbars are present.

However, in Chrome/Mac and Safari/Mac, I am seeing clientHeight and offsetHeight reporting the same value, event when there's a horizontal scrollbar beneath.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLomLpxs/

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:100px">
    <p>Inner stuff.</p>
</div>

<style>
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: gray;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    p {
        width:200px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var wrapEl = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    wrapEl.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        console.log(
            wrapEl.offsetHeight, 
            wrapEl.clientHeight,
            wrapEl.style.height);
    });
</script>
```

What am I misunderstanding? Thanks!

Comment: Both Chrome and Safari use the OSX style floating scrollbars do they not? Floating means they don't take up space, they are displayed _above_ the content.

Comment: That makes sense! Such a straightforward answer to an overly-convoluted question. Thanks.