# Understanding offsetWidth and clientWidth when css border-box is active

Tags: javascript, css, border-box

I come from this question: [Understanding offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth and -Height, respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively)

I understand that this is the case for the standard box model, is that right?

But what happens when you have something like this:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Are offsetWidth and clientWidth equal now? Does this happen always with this rule?

And what about `padding-box`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it out yourself: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvojWw

By default it is set to `box-sizing: border-box` but just change that in the styles to get different results.

It calculates `offsetWidth` and `clientWidth` for you when you click the button.

Offset width is equal to all but margins, so if you use `border-box`, you're just going to get the width you specify.

And client width is equal to all but margins and borders, so you're just going to get your `specified width - borders` when you use `border-box`.

**offsetWidth**

without `border-box`:

`offsetWidth` = `width + padding + border`

with `border-box`:

`offsetWidth` = `width`

**clientWidth**

without `border-box`:

`clientWidth` = `width + padding`

with `border-box`:

`clientWidth` = `width - border`

Comment: So you say that the box-sizing doesn't affect at all, they are always the same while border is 0, is that it?

Comment: @Vandervals Border being 0 is not enough, but if the border and padding are both 0, then the box-sizing does not change the end result. But if there is any border or padding, then the end result is different. Effectively, if you use `border-box`, you will get what you specify as `width`, but without it you will get `width + padding + border`.

Comment: @Vandervals I added a brief summary to my answer about how `offsetWidth` and `clientWidth` would turn out.