# Viewport vs Window Vs Document

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In the below code,

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
   1349
document.documentElement.clientHeight
   363
window.innerWidth
   1366
window.innerHeight
   363
window.screen.height
   768
window.screen.width
   1366
```

So, My desktop screen is 1366 px wide and 768 px height.

I learnt that,

viewport dimensions are referred using `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight`.

window dimensions are referred using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

1) What is the difference between viewport and document?

2) when does *`window.onload` Vs `document.onload`* get invoked?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Things are different when your page is bigger than your screen.

Viewport is the rectangle area where things are visible to you. The document can be larger than that, and you'll see scrollbars if so.

As for your second question: [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Here is a summary.

**Viewport:** It is your device screen.

**Window:** It is your browser window. The window can be as big as viewport or smaller.

**Document:** It is the webpage. It can be bigger than viewport or even bigger than window.

Notes:
Some websites are not meant for mobile usage. Hence, the webpage/document is much bigger than the mobile viewport, and you have to swipe to see the parts that spill outside the screen.
On a desktop, you can make the window of your browser smaller or same as the viewport/monitor.

Comment: If, *Viewport is the rectangle area where things are visible to you*, then, what is the difference between viewport and window?

Comment: @overexchange window may contain many extra things other than the viewport, such as the scrollbars, navigation bars, etc. Viewport is just the area displaying document contents. You may see the difference by comparing `window.innerWidth` and `window.outerWidth`.

Comment: which is nothing but device width and height. `screen.width` and `screen.height`

Comment: @overexchange: No, not necessarily – the browser window doesn’t have to be maximized.

Comment: In my scenario, 1) `window.innerHeight=363px` which is css pixel height. 2) `window.screen.height=768px` is device screen height. What is `window.outerHeight=728px`? Because `innerHeight` is changing on zoom-in/zoom-out.

Comment: @overexchange when you zoom, your document and the content inside will not change dimension values (if not considering percentage), it's the viewport coordinate thats changing. Your viewport will be bigger in total size (logical pixels) but smaller in unit size (physical pixels per logical pixel) when you zoom out (you can see more things), and the opposite when you zoom in. 
The outer dimension of your window will be very likely to be the size of your browser window under os screen coordinates. In summery, the sizes are under different coordinate systems.

Comment: Terminology: `window.innerHeight` is viewport(css pixel height). `window.screen.height` is device pixel height. How do I term `window.outerHeight`?

Comment: @overexchange `window.outerHeight` is browser window device pixel height. It's different with `window.screen.height` when your browser is not fullscreen. `window.screen.height` is the whole height of your monitor screen while `window.screen.height` is only the height used by your browser. When maximized `window.screen.height - window.outerHeight` should equal to your task bar size if your OS is Windows.

Comment: One supple:  How are `window.innerHeight` & `window.outerHeight` & `window.screen.height` defined in mobile device(phone) world? Any resource to learn?

Comment: @overexchange here's an article you might be interested in: http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Comment: What are we doing, when we say, `<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width">` or `<meta name="viewport" content="width = 380">`?

Comment: @overexchange This meta tag is used to specify the initial properties of the viewport when displayed on mobile browsers. You may set the viewport to a  specific width that's best to display your contents. With `device-width` your viewport will have the width of the mobile device screen. Without this meta tag, your browser may try to set the viewport width to a large value so your page layout can be the same as how it is under a desktop browser (this will usually cause your contents to be very small).

Comment: Is it true that viewport is device screen? DOM Objects are resized when I set vw or vh to them and resize the browser window

Comment: This article (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1183 - see the image on post 1) and wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport) shows that the viewport is the visible portion and not the device screen. Can you clarify this part?

Comment: This answer, while beginning correctly, gets it completely wrong in the summary: The Viewport is NOT the device screen. Its the part of the browser that shows the actual web page. As such, the window is usually bigger than the viewport.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Viewport is not the device screen, and the `innerHeight`/`innerWidth` dimensions do not include the browser "chrome" like tab bar and bookmarks bar. `window` dimensions include just the part of the browser window that display the document, including scrollbars, if any. Viewport is the part of the window that displays the document, minus scrollbars, if any.

Answer (score 10):

**document:**

*document* is an object in JavaScript that represents the DOM (Document Object Model) of your page. The document object is a representation of your entire page structure (all HTML elements etc.), so this:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

should be giving you the width of your `<html>` element

**viewport:**

using this:

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

gives you the actual visible (physical) dimensions of the window inside your browser.

**window.onLoad**

window.onload (a.k.a body.onload) gets fired after the main HTML, all CSS, all images and all other resources have been loaded and rendered.

**document.onLoad**

is called when the DOM is ready which can be prior to when images and other external content are loaded.

Comment: window.innerWidth is INCLUDING the scroll bars

Comment: Viewport is not equal to window.innerWidth or height. For getting viewport in CSS pixel always use document.documentElement.clientWidth it is equal to 100vw in CSS pixel.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best explanation is provided by [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) that I copied/pasted some important parts down below:

The document element's `Element.clientWidth` is the inner width of a document in CSS pixels, including padding (but not borders, margins, or vertical scrollbars, if present). **This is the viewport width.**

The `Window.innerWidth` is the width, in CSS pixels, of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the vertical scrollbar.

The `Window.outerWidth` is the width of the outside of the browser window including all the window chrome.