# Chrome JavaScript Width of Auto Sized Element returning 0

Tags: javascript

**How do I determine the *width* of an auto sized element (no specified `width`)?**

In example I need to determine the width of a `span` element.

The following do *not* work:

```
getElementsByTagName('span')[0].clientWidth;
getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth;
```

When looking at the Chrome developer console / computed tab the graph shows "auto x auto".

Chrome version 49.0.2623.87 m **bug**?

No frameworks.

---

Turns out that in Chrome if a parent element is set to `display: none` all the properties will return as `0` which is incredibly lame.

Comment: Impossible.... `getBoundingClientRect` *should* give you the needed result

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If it did then I wouldn't be forced to inquire. :-\

Comment: open console (Developer Tools) and see the listed errors please. Cause getBoundingClientRect is a genie/beast on his own and it has to work!

Comment: I have the same version of Chrome, and `getBoundingClientRect` still works for me...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is which is why I went to my own code and copied it. This works in Firefox fine though not Chrome? I've got a big cloud of WTH over my head right now and a hard deadline. :-\

Comment: @John believe me. You can reliably trust getBoundingClientRect if you read my answer example especially. And if your in a burning deadline - than you **should** use more often the Developer Console to prevent stupid bugs snitch unnoticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments: **it has to work**!

```js
var spanBCRw = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

console.log( spanBCRw );   // 7.09375
```

```html
<span>a</span>
```

Most probably you forgot to first target `document` where the DOM is stored

http://jsbin.com/nukufi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

---

```
var doc = document; // !!!!!!!!!!

console.log(
  doc.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].clientWidth, // 0 
  doc.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width, // 7.09375
  doc.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth // 8
);
```

`clientWidth` will work only if you set your `span` to CSS:
`display:inline-block;` or `display:block;`

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the problem I encountered so other people who have the same issue will have something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, your `getBoundingClientRect()` snippet ought to work.

Otherwise, try `offsetWidth` instead of `clientWidth`.

For more information about `offsetWidth` and other properties like it, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21064102/2773837

Comment: Ah... I forgot to mention I tried `offsetWidth`. :-\ My bad.