# Calculate the value of span's scrollWidth,offsetWidth,clientWidth

Tags: javascript, css, width

The Element.scrollWidth read-only property is a measurement of the width of an element’s content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow.The post in SO had an introduction on scrollWidth,offsetWidth,clientWidth in detail

[an introduction on scrollWidth,offsetWidth,clientWidth in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively/21064102#21064102)

[image]

Border ,padding ,margin all set to zero and overflow is hidden in the example,in imgbox1 there is a white space between images,no white space in imgbox2.Click `Run code snippet` in firefox.

```js
var imgbox1 = document.getElementById("imgbox1");
imgbox1.innerHTML += imgbox1.innerHTML;
var span1 = document.getElementById("span1");
console.log("span1.scrollWidth " + span1.scrollWidth);
var imgbox2 = document.getElementById("imgbox2");
imgbox2.innerHTML += imgbox2.innerHTML;
var span2 = document.getElementById("span2");
console.log("span2.scrollWidth " + span2.scrollWidth);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

div {
  border: 0px;
  width: 933px;
  height: 129px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgbox1">
  <span id="span1">
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
<br>
<div id="imgbox2">
  <span id="span2"><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

We got the output

```
span1.scrollWidth 39 
span2.scrollWidth 10
```

How to explain the `scrollWidth` in `span1` is 39px while `scrollWidth` in `span2` is 10px？Why the `scrollWidth` in `span1` is not 40px.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var imgbox = document.getElementById("imgbox");
  imgbox.innerHTML += imgbox.innerHTML;
  var span = imgbox.getElementsByTagName("span");
  console.log("span[0].offsetWidth " + span[0].offsetWidth);
  console.log("imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth " + (imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth));
}
```

```css
* {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 933px;
  height: 129px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgbox">
  <span>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

We get the output:

```
span[0].offsetWidth 943 
imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth 942
```

Please point out where is the 1 px difference (943-942) between them.

Comment: If you change your span to div (or change it to `display:block`), you will get the `scrollWidth` as `display:inline` elements don't seem to return the correct `scrollWidth` value. Also the white space in the first row is caused by the carriage returns after each link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from the fact that you are trying to use `span` tag as a container. As it is default `display: inline-block`. It is not applying the same calculation as you show in your image. The image discribe the all the width for a `display: block;` element.

Each display as its own width rules. To be extreme, if you would apply `display: none;`, you cannot expect to have the same rules as in your image.

So set `display: block` and rules will be respected:

```
span{
  display: block;
}
```

And you wont have any problem no matter what.

### DEMO:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var imgbox = document.getElementById("imgbox");
  imgbox.innerHTML += imgbox.innerHTML;
  var span = imgbox.getElementsByTagName("span");
  console.log("span[0].offsetWidth " + span[0].offsetWidth, '\n', "imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth " + (imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth));
}
```

```css
* {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 933px;
  height: 129px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgbox">
  <span>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the spaces between the images at the "imgbox1" is because you have spaces between the elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear).

but on the other "imgbox2" no spaces because no line breaks between images.

```
<div id="imgbox1">
  <span id="span1">
      <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a><a
         href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a><a
         href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a><a
         href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </span>
</div>
<br>
<div id="imgbox2">
  <span id="span2"><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please calculate the value 39 from `imgbox` and 10 from `imgbox2`.