# CSS Fixed position inherit width not equal to parent

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs **parent**, **child** and **element**. the div element has a **width** inherited from the **child**. The problem is the **child div has a width equals to 100%** and the element has  width equals to inherit which gives me that :

[image]

Here's what i'm looking for.

[image]

i tried diffrent ways. but no ones works. and i can't get it why the element couldnt inherit the width 200px from the parent div.

404 / 5000
I have 3 parent, child and element divs. the div element has a width inherited from the child, the problem is that the child div has a width of 100% and the element inherits from (100%) and applies it which gives me this /

here's my code :

```css
.parent{
  padding: 2px;
  height:100px;
  width:30%;
  border:solid 2px red;
}
.child{
  padding: 2px;
  border:solid 2px green;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
}

.element1{
  padding: 2px;
  width:inherit;
  border:solid 2px yellow;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
    <div class="element1">
      element1  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't inherit the computed pixel value, you inherit the 100% and you apply 100% to that element which will give you a different result

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's the problem, is there any way to inherit the computed pixel

Comment: only JS can do that if you want to keep position:fixed

Comment: Are you able to simply remove the `position: fixed`- feels like using a pull wagon instead of a dump truck to haul several yards of dirt.

Answer (score 1):

this is no the correct approach to inherit unless parent width is 100%. But this code fixes your issue by applying width inherit on child and element.

```
  .parent {
        padding: 2px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid 2px red;
    }

    .child {
        padding: 2px;
        border: solid 2px green;
        width: inherit;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .element1 {
        padding: 2px;
        width: inherit;
        border: solid 2px yellow;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that the parent can have a width like 70%. and i will still face this problem

Comment: Width: inherit copies the exact expression, not the value. If the parents width is 100% of the screen, the child copies the whole parent width behavior, not the 100% value from parent. So width inherit on child will copy the complete behavior of parent, if its expanding 50% on screen, the child will do the same. To fix this you have to explicitly define width on parent element.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with **CSS** alone, but can easily be accomplished using a few lines of **JavaScript**.

**Steps**

1. Listen for window resize events.
2. Upon resize get the parent element's width (in px) using the clientWidth or offsetWidth property.
3. Set the fixed position child elements width.
4. Apply any manual offsets to account for padding/borders/etc. Note: In this example I also set `box-sizing: border-box;` to reduce the number of required offsets.

[Window Resize Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

[clientWidth vs offsetWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21064102/8595263)

```js
 function windowResized() {
    const child = document.querySelector(".child");
    document.querySelector(".element1").style.width = `${child.clientWidth-4}px`;
    // 4px = 2*2px child padding (right/left)
  }
 
 window.addEventListener("resize", windowResized);
 windowResized();
```

```css
.parent{
  padding: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.child{
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 2px green;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.element1{
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 2px yellow;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
    <div class="element1">
      element1  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This is not specifically what you are asking but the visual you asked for it does provide.  I used `border-box` to keep things constrained in the parents box.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 2px green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.element1 {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 2px;
  width: inherit;
  border: solid 2px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
    <div class="element1">
      element1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```