# jQuery window scroll, on scoll down goes back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jQuery scroll function to create a sticky header and sometimes on a specific height (i guess) when I scroll down, goes back to top of page.

Recorded this: http://take.ms/s9mGh8

This is my function:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    $('#main').toggleClass('fixed', $(this).scrollTop() > $('#header').height()+25);
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please post a JSFiddle to share the code your using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that fixed elements doesn't take space in the DOM. So what happening here is that your header take space, you scroll the page, set the header with `position:fixed` so it doesn't take space anymore, all your elements move up and the scrollbar disappear.

To prevent that behavior, you need to add the "missing height" to the document when changing the class. A commun technique, used by [StickyKit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) for example, if to add a placeholder div.

You can see a basic code here : https://jsfiddle.net/jaL765t1/

```
var flag = false;
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  var passed_point = $(this).scrollTop() > $('#header').height()+25;

  if(passed_point && !flag){
    var surrogate = $('<div>', {
        'class' : 'js-surrogate',
        css : {
        height : $('#header').height()
      }
    });
    $('#header').before( surrogate );
    $('#main').addClass('fixed');

    flag=true;
  }else if(!passed_point && flag){
    $('#main').removeClass('fixed');
    $('#header').prev('.js-surrogate').remove();
    flag=false;
  }  
});
```

Of course, this code is not *good*, but you can easily use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 2) {
   $('#header').addClass('fixed');
   $("#content").css({"margin-top": $('#header').outerHeight() +"px"});
}else {
   $('#header').removeClass('fixed');
    $("#content").css({"margin-top":"0px"});
}
});
```

css

```
#header{
  height : 90px;
  background-color : grey;
  width : 100%;
 }
.fixed{
 position: fixed;
 top:0; left:0;
 width: 100%;  
 z-index: 9999;  
}

#content{
  height : 105vh;
}
```

Comment: in this updated code it wont flick page, its smooth effect. just check once.

Comment: this is better, but I had multiple fixed elements, and @Karl-André Gagnon gave me the right fix. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this.

If you want the header to be fixed why put the class on main?

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(e){
    //console.log($(this).scrollTop() > $("#header").height())
     //^--console.log() for testing the Boolean 
      $("#header").toggleClass("fixed", $(this).scrollTop() > $("#header").height() )
  })
})
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header{
  height:90px;
  background: purple;
}
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.content{
  height: 4000px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  Header
</div>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: I have 4-5 fixed items on page, this is why I'm adding fixed to main

Comment: well do you need to add the class to `main` or the `header`? I thought you had problems getting the sticky header set up (I thought that was the issue in the video)so that is what I showed you. I don't know what your `main` element looks like. did I help you? I like the way you use toggle class

Comment: there is any condition to get how much you still have to scroll? my function is ok when i dusplay 20 products on page, but when i have only 10 =~window height, than i have just a small scrolling area and i think this is the problem

Comment: If you just have 10 items and you can't scroll the scroll event won't get triggered. It will only get triggered while scrolling. `there is any condition to get how much you still have to scroll?` maybe you want to get the height of the page and subtract the bottom of your elements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1147711/1893672.

Comment: I need one more condition, thinking how to calculate it :) document.height - some elements. Now is triggering twice, can't understand why. First is ok, second is removing the class and moving to top